# Wordpress + bootstrap + modal

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm having some trouble with this code. Basically, 4 recent posts have to be opened in modals. This all happens inside a loop. It "works" but I have 2 issues:

- I need to click many times on the volume icon (the a tag) to open the modal
- the close button doesn't work at all

Thank you!

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '4', 'category_name' => 'evidenza' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    $i = 1;
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ):            
        $img_src = "http://127.0.0.1/bootstrap/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/".$i.".png";    
?>  
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <center>
            <img class="img-rect" width="160" height="100" alt="" src="<?php echo $img_src; ?>">

            <h3><?php echo $recent["post_title"] ?></h3>

                <br> <!--open the modal -->
                <a aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" href="#modal-news-<?php echo $recent["ID"]; ?>" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
        </center>
    </div>

    <div id="modal-news-<?php echo $recent["ID"]; ?>" class="modal fade in" aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2><?php echo $recent["post_title"] ?></h2>
                            <hr class="star-primary">
                            <img class="img-responsive img-centered img-modal" alt="Sound engineering" src="<?php echo $img_src; ?>">
                            <div class=" text-left">
                                <p><?php $content = get_post_field('post_content', $recent["ID"]);
                                echo $content; ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <center> <!--close the modal -->
                                <a data-dismiss="modal" href="#>" class="btn btn-success btn-xl ">Close</a>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    $i++;
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: remove `href="#>"` from `<a data-dismiss="modal" href="#>" class="btn btn-success btn-xl ">` don;t need it to close modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may resolve both issues.

you have wrong data attribute `data-toggle="collapse"` here to open modal should be `data-toggle="modal"`

```
<a aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" href="#modal-news-<?php echo $recent["ID"]; ?>" data-toggle="collapse">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

so replace `data-toggle="collapse"` with `data-toggle="modal"` and `href="#modal-news-<?php echo $recent["ID"]; ?>"` with `data-target="#modal-news-<?php echo $recent["ID"]; ?>"`

so above modal call button should be

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-news-<?php echo $recent["ID"]; ?>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

and inside modal, the close button remove `href="#>"`, don't need it to close the modal

```
<a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-xl">
```

Comment: perfect! I was actually quite confused about the data-toggle/dismiss also because there's not much info on bootstrap docs..thanks